# Realtek ALC888 Sound Card doesn't work after Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, realtek

yesterday i updated my Ubuntu system from 12.10 to 13.04 but since then my audio card doesn't work at all. With the previous Ubuntu version it worked fine. 
The sound card is recognized by the system (sudo aplay -l) but the sound list in System Settings - Sound - Output etc.. is empty.
Tried also to install Realtek Linux Driver from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false
but with no result.
Please HELP!!!
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.

I'll try this solution next time (hope not).

Few days ago i followed the **Sound Troubleshooting Guide** below
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

and the sound worked when i run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa; sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

and restart the machine.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

this may solve your problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139589.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.